# Drupal 9 Webforms - using webform_token and testing for defined fields

Tags: webforms, token, drupal-8

We have 6-8 different webforms on our site which submit via ajax and display the conformation message inline. I would like to put data from the form submissions into a JavaScript data layer so we can pass it on to Google Tag Manager.  I thought the most fool proof way to do this, and make sure it gets done on any new form going forward, would be to create a custom *webform-confirmation.html.twig* template and drop the fields we are interested in. Once there I am printing the submitted data by using the following TWIG:

```
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   window.dataLayer.push({
    'email': '{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:email]', webform_submission) }}',
    'timeline' : '{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values: timeline]', webform_submission) }}',
   });
</script>
```

That works great for the email field as it is on every form and always required. However some forms have a “timeline” field and other do not. For forms that have timeline I expected

```
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values: timeline]', webform_submission) }}
```

Would just print nothing, but instead I get the following output:

```
[webform_submission:values:project_timeline]
```

I have tried everything I can think of in TWIG to test to see if the webform_submission:values: timeline is defined but am unable to get anywhere. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Drupal Version 9.4.9
Webform Version: 6.1.3

Thanks,
summer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it as follows, feels like there should be a better solution but this is working....

```
  {% set project_timeline= webform_token('[webform_submission:values:project_timeline]', webform_submission) %}

  {% if project_timeline!= "[webform_submission:values:project_timeline]" %}
    'project_timeline' : '{{ project_timeline }} ',
  {% endif %}
```